# dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable can't install anything

Tags: linux, dpkg

When I try to install anything on a linux server I always get the following error:

```
Last login: Sat Aug 22 10:25:09 2015 from 27.34.97.20
root@s3:~# sudo -i
root@s3:~# su
root@s3:~# apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
nginx-common nginx-full
Suggested packages:
fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following packages will be REMOVED:
nginx-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nginx-full
The following packages will be upgraded:
nginx nginx-common
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/479 kB of archives.
After this operation, 216 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
root@s3:~#
```

Comment: Well, are those applications in your `PATH`?

Comment: Welcome to U&L, Binod! Your output did not include the prompt strings, which would have been a clue to my real question -- did you run `apt-get` as root, or a non-root user?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am in the linux server with the root user and I mistakenly  deleted the etc/nginx folder. when I try to reinstall the nginx I get those errors. I have updated my prompt stings in question, please view.

Comment: Have you tried without the `su` after `sudo -i`? sudo's `secure_path` should include the appropriate bin directories by default, and `su` shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: @steeldriver hi yes, I already did and again now, I enter `sudo -i` in command and try `su apt-get install nginx` it says No passwd entry for user 'apt-get' can you please help?

Comment: You **do not need `su`**: either use plain `sudo apt-get install nginx` within your regular user shell or `sudo -i` followed by just `apt-get install nginx` at the root shell prompt.

Comment: yes I tried the command `sudo -i apt-get install nginx` output is still same.`Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

Comment: After you run su, what is the output of `echo $PATH` and `type ldconfig`?

Comment: @JeffSchallerafter I run su the path is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` after I run `echo $path` , please help.